# MATLAB calculating distances in a loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, euclidean-distance

I'm loading a .csv file to do a few calculations in matlab. The file itself has ~1600 lines, but I'm interested in only a subset.

```
load file.csv; %load file

for i = 400:1200  %rows I am interested in

  rh_x= file(i,60); % columns interested, in column 60 for the x, 61 for y
  rh_y= file(i,61);

  rh_x2 = file(i+1, 60); % next point (x,y)
  rh_y2 = file(i+1, 61);

  p1 = [rh_x, rh_y];
  p2 = [rh_x2, rh_y2];

  coord = [p1, p2]; 
  Distan = pdist(coord, 'euclidean');  ****
  disp(Distan);
end
```

Nothing is being stored in my *Distan* variable (distance formula), where I tried to input two points. Why is that the case? I'm just wanting to calculate the distance formula for all the pairs of points in rows 60 and 61 for frames 400-1200.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you print `coord` and confirm it is the correct matrix?

Comment: Yes, I changed it above and had it disp(coord) and it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `coord` assignment to the following:

```
coord = [p1; p2];
```

The way you have it, it is storing all of the x, y pairs on the same row, as a 1x4 matrix. The above method stores it as a 2x2 matrix and `pdist` gives an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it! Had been a while since I had touched matlab.